# Get Stateless Bean from InitialContext in different thread

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x

I want to call a stateless Session Bean Deployed in JBoss 7 from java desktop application.
I create InitialContext instance and everything is ok if I lookup and call bean methods in the same thread (bean1 in following code).
But if I get bean proxy from InitialContext in another thread, the program raises an Exception when I call a method from bean (bean2 in following Code).
Partial source code I use:

```
public class Tester1 implements Runnable
{
    InitialContext ctx;
    static String beanAddr = "MobileSubscribersService_war_exploded/SubscriberEJB!com.persianswitch.ussd.ISubscriberBeanRemote";

    public void doIt()  throws NamingException
    {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
        p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
        p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pass");
        p.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        ctx = new InitialContext(p);

        ISubscriberBeanRemote bean1 =  (ISubscriberBeanRemote)ctx.lookup(beanAddr);
        int res = bean1.getLanguageByMobileNo("12345"); // this line runs good

        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ISubscriberBeanRemote bean2 = (ISubscriberBeanRemote)ctx.lookup(beanAddr);
            int res = bean2.getLanguageByMobileNo("12345"); // Throws Exception Here
        } catch (NamingException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Exception content:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:,modulename:MobileSubscribersService_war_exploded,distinctname:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@3337cdec
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:584)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getLanguageByMobileNo(Unknown Source)
    at com.persianswitch.Tester1.run(Tester1.java:52)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I want to reuse one InitialContext in multiple threads for improving performance.
Is there any mistake in my code? Are there any rule that I must know?

Answer (score 1):

InitialContext is not thread safe as its [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html) states: "An InitialContext instance is not synchronized against concurrent access by multiple threads. Multiple threads each manipulating a different InitialContext instance need not synchronize. Threads that need to access a single InitialContext instance concurrently should synchronize amongst themselves and provide the necessary locking."

Comment: thank for your reply. How can i synchronize it? which lines of code must be surrounded by synchronize block? Is there any way to use an initialContext in multiple threads?

Comment: Besides instantiation your code only accesses the context object while invoking lookup on it. Therefore, only the invocation of lookup should be synchronized as it stands.

Comment: I try it and put both lookup calls in synch block but it do not work and exception is thrown still. also in above code, lookup method calls are not done concurrent.